# Suppress technical validation error message in typo3 from the validation notifications

Tags: validation, typo3, fluid, extbase

Hi I try to get nice error messages after a form validation. I use *extbase* and *fluid* to generate a simple entity with a name and an email field that require to enter a string. I did not change anyhting. I am just using the generated codes from the extension builder.

If I leave a field empty I get the following validation error notification:

```
An error occurred while trying to call Tx_Adresstest_Controller_AdresseController->createAction()
Validation errors for argument "newAdresse"
newAdresse: Validation errors for property "name" Validation errors for property "email"
```

The second two lines are ok, but I cannot get rid off the technical notification in the first line which is absolutely not, what I want to show to the user.

thank you for your help!

**Appendix:** just found out, that it is a "flashmessage".
But I do not want to remove the  from the template, because it may also be informative as a positive feedback source for the user, like "Address has been succesfully stored".

**Appendix:** The generated and used code to test:

*New.html template*

```
<f:section name="main">
<h1>New Adresse</h1>

<f:flashMessages />

<f:form.errors>
    <div class="error">
        {error.message}
        <f:if condition="{error.propertyName}">
            <p>
                <strong>{error.propertyName}</strong>:
                <f:for each="{error.errors}" as="errorDetail">
                    {errorDetail.message}
                </f:for>
            </p>
        </f:if>
    </div>
</f:form.errors>

<f:form method="post" action="create"  name="newAdresse" object="{newAdresse}">
<label for="name">
    <f:translate key="tx_adresstest_domain_model_adresse.name" /> <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label><br />
    <f:form.textfield property="name" /><br />
<label for="email">
    <f:translate key="tx_adresstest_domain_model_adresse.email" /> <span class="required">(required)</span>
</label><br />
    <f:form.textfield property="email" /><br />
    <f:form.submit value="Create new" />
</f:form>
</f:section>
```

*AdressController.php* the controller:

```
<?php
class Tx_Adresstest_Controller_AdresseController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController {

    /**
     * adresseRepository
     *
     * @var Tx_Adresstest_Domain_Repository_AdresseRepository
     */
    protected $adresseRepository;

    /**
     * injectAdresseRepository
     *
     * @param Tx_Adresstest_Domain_Repository_AdresseRepository $adresseRepository
     * @return void
     */
    public function injectAdresseRepository(Tx_Adresstest_Domain_Repository_AdresseRepository $adresseRepository) {
        $this->adresseRepository = $adresseRepository;
    }
// ... stripped other actions ... 

    /**
     * action new
     *
     * @param $newAdresse
     * @dontvalidate $newAdresse
     * @return void
     */
    public function newAction(Tx_Adresstest_Domain_Model_Adresse $newAdresse = NULL) {
        $this->view->assign('newAdresse', $newAdresse);
    }

    /**
     * action create
     *
     * @param $newAdresse
     * @return void
     */
    public function createAction(Tx_Adresstest_Domain_Model_Adresse $newAdresse) {
        $this->adresseRepository->add($newAdresse);
        $this->flashMessageContainer->add('Your new Adresse was created.');
        $this->redirect('list');
    }

?>
```

*Adresse.php* the model:

```
    /**
     * name
     *
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * email
     *
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * Returns the name
     *
     * @return string $name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the email
     *
     * @return string $email
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return void
     */
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: We need some sample code to see what you have done wrong.

Comment: I could imagine that it is not an error in the source code but an exception that gets thrown by typo3 on purpose: because the validation fails when I leave a field of the form (name or email) empty. I Just want to configure "down" the verbosity of the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is a very big and complicated task with a lot of decisions to be made as far as how you do it. However, to solve you're immediate problem, you can perhaps add this method to your controller:

```php
/**
 * Initialize the create action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function initializeCreateAction() {
    $msgs = $this->flashMessageContainer->getAllMessagesAndFlush();
    foreach($msgs as $msg) {
        $oldMessage = $msg['message'];
        // edit old message here, if you want
        // $editedMessage = ...
        $this->flashMessageContainer->add($editedMessage);  
        // omit ^this if you just want to delete the message            
    }
}
```